# Alternate Way of dblinks in oracle

Tags: java, oracle

I am having the multiple client instance of Oracle db and one central Oracle db.
we are required to communicate to Central db from client db without creating the dblinks. We are having the application developed on java.

Problems:
we cant have the central db connections in properties file or in any other classes. 
We cant create dblinks to client database.
Its like one running application on client side is having its own db instance.

Please suggest us how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you're trying to communicate with a database... but you're not allowed to connect to it?  Can you explain why you're not allowed to create the database links or the database connection information?  If this is some security thing, like you don't want to expose that central database, perhaps a proxy like Oracle connection manager can help.  Then you can have clients talk to the proxy, and that proxy talks to the central database.  Once the configuration is done it all acts like a normal connection.

Comment: Clients are not ready to perform any DDL operations on there dbs. 
 Our requirement is like:
We wants to have the data in sync. so if client delete any record then same record should be deleted from our db (central db) as well. Only approach we can follow is by using java code.

Comment: consider a REST API, and have your application or database reach out via HTTPS to interact with the other database(s)

Comment: Thanks for Advising me for REST API. It will work without exposing any thing. How i can be that silly. Anyways thanks sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to develop your own protocol.

Any time a transaction happens on one database, you dump the DML associated with it, and you run it on the other ones.

- The source database has any modification audited (see SQL-trace or V$SQL...). This is one java daemon, or can also be PL/SQL.
- You must have a queue to handle the DML or DDL orders and run them after that in the same order on any other database.
- The destination database collects the DML or DDL, let's say on a Samba share or something, and run them locally. This can be a java daemon doing the job.

Hope it helps and good luck!

Comment: There should be the logical connection between source and destination db.
To maintain the db queue. We cant do anything on source db. We have to handle the communication from java code only.

Is there any way trigger the web-service from oracle  or something like that.

Comment: If you can't do anything on the source db, its impossible. You must at some point act on the database to enable tracing. It is possible to have it done once by the DBA, so that tracing is logged all in **a file**, on a share. Then you can access it with java from clients and apply modification you read there. Pretty weird requirement anyway.

Comment: Any hopes from java code. We can't access the database as DBA. We are having read only privileges.

Comment: Not you, but **your DBA** can do things. If you can't talk to your DBA, it seems to me you are somehow trying to hack the database... A solution would be to listen to the ***SQL*Net*** transactions on the (unencrypted) network, parse them and run them on your clients.

Comment: I checked with DBA regarding that , He told me like there are so many source instances. so logically its not feasible logging all changes from all the machines and update at end. This application build in 2003 and having so many client dbs.    

Any feasible way to done it by java code.